# Realm: Not Getting Data Back

Tags: android, realm

So I get a list of 400 objects and put it into a collection to `copyToRealm()`. Then, I do a `findAllSorted()` and I get an empty array back. So I debugged to try to figure out what is wrong. I checked the Realm database with Stethos and I see my objects I created there, but when I do `findAllSorted()`, it says there is nothing. Is there something about `copyToRealm()` where it is asynchronous or something. Because after that line where I call `copyToRealm()`, I would expect there to be results afterwards but there are not.

Comment: Consider adding code so that we know what exactly you're doing. For example, if AsyncTask is involved, etc. (and also Realm version)

Comment: I am not suppose to put code out as this is code I am not suppose to share. But yes, copyToRealm code is in an asynchronous call's callback, but so is the findAllSorted, so it shouldn't be a race condition unless copyToRealm isn't finished by the time I called findAllSorted, but if code is executed synchronously, that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: So to clarify a little more, we have an AsyncTask. In it's doInBackground, we do the copyToRealm() call on that huge list. At the last lines of doInBackground, we call the callback that was passed in, on the UI thread via runOnUiThread. In the callback, that was where I called findAllSorted. What confused me about this bug is that while the task is asynchronous, everything in the doInBackground should be synchronous. So it first makes the batch call with copyToRealm(), then once that is done, it executes a the callback which then calls findAllSorted()

Comment: This is fixed now. We moved the lines where it called the callback on the UI thread to onPostExecute of AsyncTask. So I guess when the doInBackground is done, it calls onPostExecute. But the entire code in doInBackground is synchronous as well. So it's fixed, but I don't understand why.

Comment: You should be using `RealmChangeListener` instead of trying to manually read the version which *might not be updated yet* on the UI thread manually

Comment: I did not know that exists. Thank you for letting me know about that. But I did solve it a different way and it worked. However, there is still once concept that elludes me, which is what I mentioned previously. Why would my table not be updated yet after the copyToRealm() call? Is it asynchronous or something?

Comment: No, `copyToRealm()` is synchronous, and everything in the transaction updates *immediately*. But updates across threads are not immediate, Realm coordinates it for looper threads, and when it is done then RealmChangeListeners are called.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I thought that threads all share the same Realm so updates are all instantaneous. I did not know it took time when off the UI thread. One question though, why does relocating code to onPostExecute() work then?

Comment: Not sure. It should work about 40% of the time if the write is in `doInBackground()` and the read is in `onPostExecute()`. There is no guarantee that Realm has already updated on the next event loop (which is when `onPostExecute()` is run). Realm instances are thread-local due to the MVCC architecture which allows reads on any thread without locks, but this also means that updates aren't immediate. Generally, `RealmChangeListener` is the safe choice, but you must keep the `RealmResults<T>` as a field variable.

Comment: I see, thanks. I don't know how to close this question though O,o

Answer (score 0):

The answer is found in the comments above.